# Does values_list prevent you to access to field names?

Tags: python, django, list, templates, field

I'm trying to use `{{ field.name }}` in my template but I can't get access to it. I'm using `values_list`.

views.py:

```
objects = Ingredient.objects.select_related('stock').filter(account=account, exists=True).values_list('id', 'name', 'stock__stock', 'comments')[:50]
```

template.html:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% for field in object %}
        {% if field.name != 'id' %}
            <td>{{ field}}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can assume I'm showing every field in `values_list` except by `id` which I'm using only for JavScript functions but I don't want to show it in my for loop iteration. But I can't get access to `{{ field.name }}`, I tried by printing it in the html but I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. You can verify this with `python manage.py shell`. [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) will return list of tuples of the fields' values.

Comment: Then how can I get access to the field name when I'm using values_list?

Comment: You can't. That's part of `values_list` constraints. Can you use `values` instead? Or `.only`?